# Vector space whose dimension is nontrivial to determine

Tags: vector-spaces

Is there any vector space which is easy to proven to be a vector space but whose dimension is nontrivial to determine?

I want such a case as an exercise for the students.

Comment: te solutions of a linear system $Ax = 0$, where the rank of $A$ is not trivial to determine ?

Comment: Solution space of a linear differential equation?

Comment: The span, over the rationals, of the zeros of the zeta function in the critical strip but off the half-line.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting close votes--the context is quite clear from the final sentence of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the dual space of a finite-dimensional vector space is a good example for that.

What qualifies as a non-trivial method to determine the dimension? As @Tlön Uqbar Orbis Tertius mentioned in his comment, this can mean 'not easy to calculate the dimension by hand', in the case of a vector space given by ker($A$), but then the dimension is determined by rank $A$, even if it's hard to compute.

Another way to interpret the question is a vector space where you know that it's a vector space (because it's a subspace of a known vector space), but you don't immediately see the dimension.

Finite-dimensional spaces of functions come to mind here, and as a variant of the non-full-rank matrix, you could take a space spanned by some polynomials which are not linearly independent.

But among the sub-spaces of functions there is one lovely concept where you actually need to do some work to get the dimension: **the dual space of a finite-dimensional space.** The proof is not too long ([Prove that vector space and dual space have same dimension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128436/prove-that-vector-space-and-dual-space-have-same-dimension)).

Comment: Thanks! This is really a good example. Personally I indeed struggled to prove this simple yet important fact.